# Is it possible to use an existing ELB in a new CFT without the ELB being exported by an existing CF stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I was wondering if it is possible to use a existing ELB thats not being exported by a CF stack to be referenced in a new CFT and used in the resulting CF stack. The only resources online seem like an existing CFT needs export the ELB in order for a new CFT to import it. However, it seems like it should be possible for a new CFT to reference and use an existing ELB that is not exported by another CFT. I tried referencing by name as a parameter but couldn't find a supported parameter type for ELBs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible. Using an export from a CF stack is basically asking AWS to pass the string representation of that resource to the other stack, on your behalf. So if you export a `AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer` (and it [returns its ARN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer.html#w2ab1c21c10d129c25c10)), you can just pass a Load Balancer to another stack by providing the same ARN.

In other words, I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work:

```yaml
Parameters:
  MyServicesLoadBalancer:
    Type: "String"
    Description: "ARN of the Load Balancer"

Resources:
  MyServicesLoadBalancerListener:
    Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener"
    Properties:
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref MyServicesLoadBalancer
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: fixed-response
          FixedResponseConfig:
            ContentType: "text/plain"
            MessageBody: "You've reached the listener! Congrats!"
            StatusCode: "200"
```

Comment: Turns out all I had to do was use the ELB's name in the LoadBalancerNames section of the AutoScalingGroup